# Why is this transaction not rolled back when using XACT_ABORT?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to learn things about implicit and explicit transactions.
I have a table with three columns and a check constraint on age (must be <10)

Now I have the following code where I expected to be rolled back because I have `XACT_ABORT ON`. But the first statement is imported to the table. How come?

```sql
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
SET XACT_ABORT ON;

INSERT INTO tblbegintran (firstname, lastname, age)
VALUES ('gijs', 'adsafads', 6)
 
INSERT INTO tblbegintran (firstname, lastname, age)
VALUES ('gijss', 'dafds', 17)
COMMIT TRAN;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, let's start at `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS`. From [SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-implicit-transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> **When OFF, each of the preceding T-SQL statements is bounded by an unseen BEGIN TRANSACTION and an unseen COMMIT TRANSACTION statement. When OFF, we say the transaction mode is *autocommit***. If your T-SQL code visibly issues a BEGIN TRANSACTION, we say the transaction mode is explicit.

As you don't have an explicit `BEGIN TRANSACTION` for the transaction above you are in *autocommit*; I have bolded the relevant sentences. From [Auto-Commit Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/auto-commit-mode?view=sql-server-ver15):

> In *auto-commit mode*, every database operation is a transaction that is committed when performed. This mode is suitable for many real-world transactions that consist of a single SQL statement. It is unnecessary to delimit or specify completion of these transactions. In databases without transaction support, auto-commit mode is the only supported mode. In such databases, statements are committed when they are executed and there is no way to roll them back; they are therefore always in auto-commit mode.
>
> If the underlying DBMS does not support auto-commit mode transactions, the driver can emulate them by manually committing each SQL statement as it is executed.
>
> If a batch of SQL statements is executed in auto-commit mode, it is data source-specific when the statements in the batch are committed. They can be committed as they are executed or as a whole after the entire batch has been executed. Some data sources may support both of these behaviors and may provide a way of selecting one or the others. In particular, if an error occurs in the middle of the batch, it is data source-specific whether the already-executed statements are committed or rolled back. Thus, interoperable applications that use batches and require them to be committed or rolled back as a whole should execute batches only in manual-commit mode.

And finally, from [SET XACT_ABORT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> When SET XACT_ABORT is ON, if a Transact-SQL statement raises a run-time error, the entire transaction is terminated and rolled back.

So here, each of your statements are being implicitly committed *after* they are completed, as you are in autocommit mode and so each is in it's own transaction. Thus your first statement that meets the requirements of the `CHECK CONSTRAINT` is committed, and then the second statement fails, and *that* transaction is rolled back. This means that `XACT_ABORT` is only rolling back the transaction that failed in your attempt; where `age` has a value of `17`.

To get the behaviour you want, you would either need to use `SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON` or wrap the whole thing in an explicit transaction. Example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.tblbegintran (age int CHECK (age < 10));
GO
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
INSERT INTO tblbegintran (age)
VALUES (6);
INSERT INTO tblbegintran (age)
VALUES (17);
COMMIT TRAN;
GO

SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO tblbegintran (age)
VALUES (7);
INSERT INTO tblbegintran (age)
VALUES (17);
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
GO
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON;
INSERT INTO tblbegintran (age)
VALUES (8);
INSERT INTO tblbegintran (age)
VALUES (17);
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
GO
SELECT * --Only 6 appears
FROM dbo.tblbegintran;
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.tblbegintran;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017l&fiddle=da7180193745acd7b209713020a07a56)

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. Is my transaction not rolled back because the system sees it as two seperate transations?

Comment: *"When OFF, each of the preceding T-SQL statements is bounded by an unseen BEGIN TRANSACTION and an unseen COMMIT TRANSACTION statement."* @KeesLasser . The documentation, which i bolded, tells you exactly what's happening.

Comment: I got you explanation and understand it when implicit_transaction is OFF.
When i read DOCS it says: **When ON, the system is in implicit transaction mode. This means that if @@TRANCOUNT = 0, any of the following Transact-SQL statements begins a new transaction**

In that case, why is your last statement not imported?

Comment: Your first `INSERT` statement would make `@@TRANCOUNT` have the value `1`, @KeesLasser , so the latter `INSERT` would not start a new one... 0 <> 1.

Comment: thank you. SO in that way it sees the two inserts as one transaction.

Comment: Not in your attempt, @KeesLasser , no. That is what I, and the documentation, have been telling you and that is *why* your attempt isn't working as you expect; they are 2 transactions not 1 implicit one.

Comment: Excuse me, i mean your third 'set' statement where implicit transactions is ON.

Comment: Yes, that would be seen as all wrapped in one implicit transaction, @KeesLasser .